# Save a matrix as an image

Tags: image, matlab

I have a matrix `finalMat` of data type double with values in the range of 0 to 255. It actually corresponds to some image. I am displaying it as below:

```
imshow(finalMat, []);
```

But when I try to save it using the below code, the image saved is completely white.

```
imwrite(finalMat,'myImage.jpeg','JPEG');
```

I want to save the image on disk without changing the values in the finalMat matrix. When I read the saved image i.e myImage.jpeg, I must get the same values as in finalMat. Can somebody please help in saving the image?

Answer (score 3):

[`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) first checks the datatype prior to writing the file to determine how to treat the values in the input. If the input is a `double`, is assumes that the range is 0 to 1. If the input is a `uint8`, then it assumes [0, 255].

Your two options are to cast the data as `uint8` or normalize it between 0 and 1 and keep it as a `double`.

**Cast as a `uint8`**

For your *specific* example, you already have data between 0 and 255 and presumably don't want that data scaled, so you'll likely want to go the `uint8` cast route.

```
imwrite(uint8(finalMat), 'file.jpg');
```

Keep in mind that since you have a `double` image matrix, this will force all the numbers to be integer values so it may not be *exactly* equal when you load it back into MATLAB.

**Normalize Image Data**

More generally speaking, you'll typically want to go with the normalization approach using [`mat2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html) to do the normalization for you which allows you to utilize the full 8-bit range.

```
imwrite(mat2gray(finalMat), 'file.jpg')
```

> **NOTE**: You mention that you want the resulting image to be *exactly* equal to the matrix that you're passing into it. Unfortunately, your input data is a `double` which requires 64 bits per pixel. **None** of the imaging formats supported by MATLAB can actually store *all* 64 bits so you're going to end up with some differences regardless of how you do this. If you want to minimize this effect, look for an image format that supports 16 or 32-bit data (the JPEG you're currently creating is 8-bit). Also, I would recommend *against* using JPEG as this is potentially a lossy type of compression. If you want lossless compression, go with a TIFF or PNG.

Comment: I definitely would not use `uin8`, as it is just a type cast. Probably better `mat2gray`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Isn't `imwrite` just going to cast it as a `uint8` upon writing anyhow even if it's a double going in? The documentation says that it gets converted to an 8-bit image: "If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes that the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values. If the data in A is single, convert A to double before writing to a GIF or TIFF file."

Comment: Yes, but when you `uint8()` an image, it just cast the values. `mat2gray` is the same thing, but ensuring that it gets scaled also. An uncontroled use of `uint8` will lead to unknown results due to casting.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ok sure. I just assumed that the data was already scaled given that the original question stated that the values were [0,255]

Comment: Yeah, you are rigth. But its a good programming practice to account for all  cases. Thats why for loops in C shoudl be written as `for(int i=0; i<max;i++)`, to avoid unexpected infinite loops. Same idea

Comment: @AnderBiguri Completely agree, answer has been updated.

Comment: @Suever when I load back the image into MATLAB, it will be between [0 255]. But the values in matrices are different. I want values in loaded back matrix to be same as the matrix from which I am saving the image. How do I get that?